# How to create a BMI calculator using JavaScript with options to choose between BMI in Kgs/metters or BMI in Lbs/feet

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day all,

I am currently coding BMI calculator for my project.
The calculator is already set to work in Lbs/feet, but I would like to add an option where I can be able to choose between Kgs/meters or Lbs/feet.

I have created the html code for it and just need the JavaScript part of it to make it work.

Please note that the formula being used for Lbs is:

```
((mass / 2.2046) / ((height/3.28) * (height/3.28))).toFixed(2)
```

And if I wanted to calculate the BMI in Kgs / meters, for formula would be:

```
(mass / (height * height)).toFixed(2)
```

Please see below what I have done so far:
Your help is always appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```js
// BMI Calculator
  
const myForm     = document.getElementById('my-form');

myForm.oninput = () => {
    myForm.result.value = bmiCalculator(myForm.height.value, myForm.mass.value);


function bmiCalculator(height, mass)  {   
    return ((mass / 2.2046) / ((height/3.28) * (height/3.28))).toFixed(2)

    }
}
```

```css
 fieldset { margin-top: 1em;
}
 label { 
   display: inline-block; width: 10em; text-align: left; 
  }
  input { 
    font-size: .9em; text-align: left; display: inline-block; width: 10em;
  }
   output::before {  
     content: ''; 
  }
  output { 
      font-weight: bold; width: 16em; border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey; display: block; margin: .8em; float: right; text-align: right;
  }
  append { 
      display: inline-block; width: 10em; text-align: center; 
  }
```

```html
<h2>Body Mass Index Calculator</h2>

  <!-- Used oninput to display the results instantly-->
  <!-- If I wanted to calculate the result on a click, I would use onsubmit-->

  <form action="" oninput="return mySubmitFunction(event)" id="my-form">

    <fieldset>
     <legend>Please Choose which BMI you would like to use :</legend>
     <append>BMI in Kgs / Meters <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="bmiInKgs"></append>
     <append>BMI in Lbs / Feet <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="bmiInLbs"></append>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend><b>Calculate Your BMI :</b></legend>
      <br>
     <label>Height in Feet: <input type="number" id="height" name="height" step=any min=0></label>
      <label>Mass / Weight in lbs: <input type="number" id="mass" class="mass" step=any min=0></label> 
    </fieldset>
    
    
    <fieldset><br>
      <legend><b>BMI Result  :</b></legend>
      <output id="result" name="result" value='0'></output>
  
      <br><br>
      <button type="reset">Reset Calculator!</button>
    </fieldset></fieldset>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand all you need is to access the radio value, correct?

```
if (myForm.bmi.value == "bmiInKgs")
  // Calculate Kg
else {
  // Calculate Lbs
}
```

```js
// BMI Calculator
  
const myForm     = document.getElementById('my-form');

myForm.oninput = () => {
if (myForm.bmi.value == "bmiInKgs") {
    myForm.result.value = bmiCalculator(myForm.height.value, myForm.mass.value);
} else {
    myForm.result.value = bmiCalculator(myForm.height.value/3.28, myForm.mass.value/2.2046);
}

function bmiCalculator(height, mass)  {   
    return (mass / (height * height)).toFixed(2)
    }
}
```

```css
fieldset { margin-top: 1em;
}
 label { 
   display: inline-block; width: 10em; text-align: left; 
  }
  input { 
    font-size: .9em; text-align: left; display: inline-block; width: 10em;
  }
   output::before {  
     content: ''; 
  }
  output { 
      font-weight: bold; width: 16em; border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey; display: block; margin: .8em; float: right; text-align: right;
  }
  append { 
      display: inline-block; width: 10em; text-align: center; 
  }
```

```html
<h2>Body Mass Index Calculator</h2>

  <!-- Used oninput to display the results instantly-->
  <!-- If I wanted to calculate the result on a click, I would use onsubmit-->

  <form action="" oninput="return mySubmitFunction(event)" id="my-form">

    <fieldset>
     <legend>Please Choose which BMI you would like to use :</legend>
     <append>BMI in Kgs / Meters <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="bmiInKgs" checked="checked"></append>
     <append>BMI in Lbs / Feet <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="bmiInLbs"></append>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend><b>Calculate Your BMI :</b></legend>
      <br>
     <label>Height: <input type="number" id="height" name="height" step=any min=0></label>
      <label>Mass / Weight: <input type="number" id="mass" class="mass" step=any min=0></label> 
    </fieldset>
    
    
    <fieldset><br>
      <legend><b>BMI Result  :</b></legend>
      <output id="result" name="result" value='0'></output>
  
      <br><br>
      <button type="reset">Reset Calculator!</button>
    </fieldset></fieldset>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// BMI Calculator
  
const myForm     = document.getElementById('my-form');

myForm.oninput = () => {
if (myForm.bmi.value == "bmiInKgs") {
    myForm.result.value = bmiCalculator(myForm.height.value, myForm.mass.value);
} else {
    myForm.result.value = bmiCalculator(myForm.height.value/3.28, myForm.mass.value/2.2046);
}

function bmiCalculator(height, mass)  {   
    return (mass / (height * height)).toFixed(2)
    }
}
```

```css
fieldset { margin-top: 1em;
}
 label { 
   display: inline-block; width: 10em; text-align: left; 
  }
  input { 
    font-size: .9em; text-align: left; display: inline-block; width: 10em;
  }
   output::before {  
     content: ''; 
  }
  output { 
      font-weight: bold; width: 16em; border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey; display: block; margin: .8em; float: right; text-align: right;
  }
  append { 
      display: inline-block; width: 10em; text-align: center; 
  }
```

```html
<h2>Body Mass Index Calculator</h2>

  <!-- Used oninput to display the results instantly-->
  <!-- If I wanted to calculate the result on a click, I would use onsubmit-->

  <form action="" oninput="return mySubmitFunction(event)" id="my-form">

    <fieldset>
     <legend>Please Choose which BMI you would like to use :</legend>
     <append>BMI in Kgs / Meters <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="bmiInKgs" checked="checked"></append>
     <append>BMI in Lbs / Feet <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="bmiInLbs"></append>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend><b>Calculate Your BMI :</b></legend>
      <br>
     <label>Height: <input type="number" id="height" name="height" step=any min=0></label>
      <label>Mass / Weight: <input type="number" id="mass" class="mass" step=any min=0></label> 
    </fieldset>
    
    
    <fieldset><br>
      <legend><b>BMI Result  :</b></legend>
      <output id="result" name="result" value='0'></output>
  
      <br><br>
      <button type="reset">Reset Calculator!</button>
    </fieldset></fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).